# Prove that $A = \{P(A)\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that

If $A=\{B\},
B=\{\{\},A\}
$ then $A=\{P(A)\}$

$P(A)$ denotes the power set of $A$.

I have studied well founded set theory but this proof calls for Anti Foundation Axiom. I am not familiar with proving such statements. Can anyone provide a hint?

Image for reference of problem from Vicious Circles:
[image]

Comment: That is definitely not true. The sizes are different.

Comment: The two are **not** equal. The set $\{  \}$ (emptyset) is an element of $\mathcal P(A)$ but it is not an element of $A$.

Comment: I have changed the statement to match the question. It included brackets around $P(A)$ and also added an image for reference to the original question.

Comment: Yes, $B=P(A)$. So ${P(A)} = {B} = A$.

Comment: @Kenta That is exactly what i thought too!

Comment: "*Supposing that $a$ and $b$ are sets satisfying...*" then we do arrive at the absurd result that $a=\{\mathcal{P}(a)\}$.  Most people who glance at the problem will just look at the result and see it as an absurd result, not looking at the hypotheses and see that the hypotheses are also absurd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is a singleton, so $B=\{\emptyset,A\}=P(A)$. Thus, $A=\{B\}=\{P(A)\}$.